# How to get the raw SQL of the query being executed by SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlalchemy

we are using SQL alchemy as the ORM for our project. i am trying to get & analyze the  raw SQL  that gets generated (via SQL alchemy) for performance purposes.
can somebody please let me know if there is a way to gather the raw SQL before it gets committed to the database.

Comment: `print MyModel.objects.all().query` should give you the raw query.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `echo=True` when instantiating your engine:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine("mysql://localhost/mydb", echo=True)
```

This causes all SQL statements to be logged via normal Python logging. You can easily capture these messages to a file by using the appropriate log configuration, as shown in these [Python logging examples](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html#simple-examples).

Reference: [SQLAlchemy Engine Configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. by setting echo to True the sql's get displayed on the command prompt. I am looking for a way by which i can collect the raw sql in the SQL Alchemy event (say:before_flush)  and programmatically check the raw SQL.

Comment: @Tanu, Actually, setting `echo=True` makes those statements get logged via regular Python logging. All you have to do is either set up a logging file hander or set up syslog appropriately and you'll be able to easily capture those messages.